# Send data to controller using apex:actionsupport and apex:param

Tags: apex, visualforce

Is it possible to send data to my controller using these two actions. I currently have an actionfunction in place, but i am trying to use a different method instead because the actionfunction is being used to rerender 5 inputfields and when it rerenders it cause errors.

When a user types into an inputfield and triggers the onblur event I am trying to take that data they put into that inputfield send it to the controller, then the controller finds a detail about that inputfield, and sends it back to a outputtext associated with that field. This will create dynamically loaded content. However the problem i am facing is that when i try and do this and some required fields are there it causes errors and it fails to load any dynamic content because the actionfunction seems to have failed.

Comment: actionfunction with the attribute immediate=true should skip validation checks. Adding some code would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks just fixed it! I saw the immediate after a bit of research. But thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set immediate=true to actionFunction stops the validation error.